# Disqus widget tab gone

Tags: widget, disqus

Can't find information on it anywhere. Lots of tutorials show a simple widget setup on disqus account, but my account seems to be missing Widgets tab from Tools section. Any ideas? Was there an update or something recently that removed it? Do you know anything?

Comment: did you try disqus support?

Comment: yeah trying to find some widgets but cannot find the tab.